# Select all of an element between the current element and the next of the current element

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT 1.0 (preferably), How can I select all of an element which occurs between the current element and the next time the current element occurs?

Say I have this XML (edited):

```
<root>
    <heading_1>Section 1</heading_1>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>Section 1.1</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <heading_3>Section 1.1.1</heading_3>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>Section 1.2</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <footnote>...</footnote>
    <heading_1>Section 2</heading_1>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>Section 2.1</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <list_2>...</list_2>
    <heading_3>Seciton 2.1.1</heading_3>
    <para>...</para>
    <heading_2>Section 2.2</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <footnote>...</footnote>
</root>
```

When processing `heading_1` I want to select all of `heading_2` between the heading I am processing and the next `heading_1`. The same for selecting `heading_3` when processing `heading_2` etc. you get the picture.

Comment: Jrod: I have opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16188341/2115381)  based on your changed description. Because I think this is an interesting problem. Also I put a first possible answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
following-sibling::heading_2[generate-id(preceding-sibling::heading_1[1]) = 
                             generate-id(current())]
```

Working example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="heading_1" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="heading_1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="following-sibling::heading_2[generate-id(
                                                preceding-sibling::heading_1[1]) = 
                                             generate-id(current())]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="heading_2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="following-sibling::heading_3[generate-id(
                                                preceding-sibling::heading_2[1]) = 
                                             generate-id(current())]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result when run on your sample input:

```
<root>
  <heading_1>
    <heading_2>
      <heading_3>...</heading_3>
    </heading_2>
    <heading_2 />
  </heading_1>
  <heading_1>
    <heading_2>
      <heading_3>...</heading_3>
    </heading_2>
    <heading_2 />
  </heading_1>
</root>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain the select? I'm trying to modify it so that I can retain all the other elements than in your example were cut. For example, in my processing of `heading_1` I am trying to use `following-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::heading_2[1]) = generate-id(current())]` but this doesn't seem to select anything.

Comment: +1, good answer. @BigJord: try changing `heading_2` to `heading_1` in the code snippet you just gave. I'll leave it to JLRishe to explain the XPath expression.

Comment: @BigJord `generate-id()` produces a unique ID for any node, and can be used (as in my example) to identify when two selected nodes are actually the same node. Given that, the expression I gave can be read in human language as something like "select all following `heading_2`s whose first preceding `heading_1` is the same node as the current node." As LarsH says, your expression should work if you change the `heading_2` to `heading_1`.

Comment: For some reason, `following-sibling::*[generate-id(preceding-sibling::heading_1[1]) = generate-id(current())]` doesn't work right in my XSLT. Instead of selecting all following siblings up to the next heading_1, it is selecting to rest of the document from that heading onwards (and then doing it again for the next heading, etc.). Why is that?

Comment: Not sure. Could you post the current state of your XSLT in your question above?

Comment: I've added some more detail to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below XPath to select the heading2 when processing heading 1.

```
(/root/heading_1/following-sibling::heading_1/preceding-sibling::heading_2) | (/root/heading_1[preceding-sibling::heading_1]/following-sibling::heading_2)
```

Comment: This will just select all of the `heading_2`s in the document every time.

Comment: @JLRishe: Actually, it will select only the `heading_2`s that are *children of the `/root` element*; and those only if there are at least two `heading_1` elements that are also children of the `/root` element. With the given sample input, those caveats don't make any difference, but it's not clear that there will always be at least two `heading_1`s.

Comment: @LarsH Good points. I left out part of what you said for brevity (assuming that the document will always have the general structure given in OP), and neglected to think about what would happen if there were only one `heading_1`. My point, though, is that this answer doesn't solve the given question at all.