# Create an hierarchical xml form an "flat" xml a like book description

Tags: xslt

This is a following up question to question to ["Select all of an element between the current element and the next of the current element"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16145859/2115381). Even If I'm not sure if creating a new question is the right way I do it anyway. Because the original question was answered but changed afterwards. So in my view the changed questions is open. Also I think the changed question should be put back in the stat were it fit to the answer.

**The question is how to create an hierarchical xml form an "flat"  xml like a book description.**

The input xml is something like

```
<root>
    <heading_1>Section 1</heading_1>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>Section 1.1</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <heading_3>Section 1.1.1</heading_3>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>Section 1.2</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <footnote>...</footnote>
    <heading_1>Section 2</heading_1>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>Section 2.1</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <list_2>...</list_2>
    <heading_3>Seciton 2.1.1</heading_3>
    <para>...</para>
    <heading_2>Section 2.2</heading_2>
    <para>...</para>
    <footnote>...</footnote>
</root>
```

Each `<heading_*>` should be interpreted as start of an `<section>`
The expected output xml is.

```
<section>
    <title>Section 1</title>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <section>
        <title>Section 1.1</title>
        <para>...</para>
        <section>
            <title>Section 1.1.1</title>
            <para>...</para>
            <list_1>...</list_1>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>Section 1.2</title>
        <para>...</para>
        <footnote>...</footnote>
    </section>
</section>
<section>
    <title>Section 2</title>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <section>
        <title>Section 2.1</title>
        <para>...</para>
        <list_1>...</list_1>
        <list_2>...</list_2>
        <section>
            <title>Section 2.1.1</title>
            <para>...</para>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>Section 2.2</title>
        <para>...</para>
        <footnote>...</footnote>
    </section>
</section>
```

Also I tried a while  to find a solution for this  bases on the original solution from  [@JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146259/2115381). So I found one and like to put it here as answer as one possibility. And I hope  for a more comprehensible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my current solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="headerLevel_txt">
        <heading name="__none__" level="0"/>
        <heading name="heading_1" level="1"/>
        <heading name="heading_2" level="2"/>
        <heading name="heading_3" level="3"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="headerLevel" select="exsl:node-set($headerLevel_txt)" />


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" >
                <xsl:with-param name="ch" select="h1" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="heading_1" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="heading_1 | heading_2 | heading_3" >
        <xsl:param name="previousheaader" select="'__none__'" />

        <xsl:variable name="endOfLevel" >
            <xsl:call-template name="endOfLevel">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentheaader" select="name()" />
                <xsl:with-param name="previousheaader" select="$previousheaader" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test ="$endOfLevel != 'end'" >
            <section>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </title>

                <!-- following siblings including next heading  -->
                <xsl:variable name="fsinh" select="following-sibling::*[ 
                              generate-id( preceding-sibling::*
                                           [
                                             name() = 'heading_1' or name() = 'heading_2' or  name() = 'heading_3'
                                           ][1]
                                          ) = generate-id(current()) ]" />

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fsinh[ position()!=last()]" >
                        <xsl:with-param name="previousheaader" select="name()" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>

                <!-- following siblings heading same as next   -->
                <xsl:variable name="fshsan" select="following-sibling::*[  
                              name() = name($fsinh[last()]) and
                              generate-id( preceding-sibling::*
                                           [
                                             name() = name(current())
                                           ][1]
                                          ) = generate-id(current()) ]" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$fshsan" >
                    <xsl:with-param name="previousheaader" select="name()" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>

            </section>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="endOfLevel">
        <xsl:param name ="currentheaader"/>
        <xsl:param name ="previousheaader"/>
        <!-- The previous heading ends if the current has an higher level (smaller level number)-->
        <xsl:variable name ="cl" select="number($headerLevel/heading[@name=$currentheaader]/@level)"/>
        <xsl:variable name ="pl" select="number($headerLevel/heading[@name=$previousheaader]/@level)"/>
        <xsl:if test ="$cl &lt; $pl">end</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will generate the following output:

```
<root>
  <section>
    <title>Section 1</title>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <section>
      <title>Section 1.1</title>
      <para>...</para>
      <section>
        <title>Section 1.1.1</title>
        <para>...</para>
        <list_1>...</list_1>
      </section>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>Section 1.2</title>
      <para>...</para>
      <footnote>...</footnote>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title>Section 2</title>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <section>
      <title>Section 2.1</title>
      <para>...</para>
      <list_1>...</list_1>
      <list_2>...</list_2>
      <section>
        <title>Seciton 2.1.1</title>
        <para>...</para>
      </section>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>Section 2.2</title>
      <para>...</para>
      <footnote>...</footnote>
    </section>
  </section>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic solution that will work for any heading depth:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kChildHeader" 
           match="/*/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'heading_')]"
           use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                       [local-name() = 
                        concat('heading_', 
                               substring-after(local-name(current()), '_') - 1
                              )][1]
                            )"/>
  <xsl:key name="kChildItem" 
           match="/*/*[not(starts-with(local-name(), 'heading_'))]"
           use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                             [starts-with(local-name(), 'heading_')][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="heading_1" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'heading_')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildHeader', generate-id()) |
                                   key('kChildItem', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<root>
  <heading_1>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>
      <para>...</para>
      <heading_3>
        <para>...</para>
        <list_1>...</list_1>
      </heading_3>
    </heading_2>
    <heading_2>
      <para>...</para>
      <footnote>...</footnote>
    </heading_2>
  </heading_1>
  <heading_1>
    <para>...</para>
    <list_1>...</list_1>
    <heading_2>
      <para>...</para>
      <list_1>...</list_1>
      <list_2>...</list_2>
      <heading_3>
        <para>...</para>
      </heading_3>
    </heading_2>
    <heading_2>
      <para>...</para>
      <footnote>...</footnote>
    </heading_2>
  </heading_1>
</root>
```

Comment: I  just had to realize, that this nice solution does not work with all xlst processors (e.g. xsltproc) because a problem with current() in xls:key