# XSL Rewrite a straight xml structure to nested xml

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, tags

I've a XML structure like:

`<TOP>top</TOP>`
`<HDR>header</HDR>`
`<LINE>line1</LINE>`
`<LINE>line2</LINE>`
`<LINE>line3</LINE>`
`<HDR>header</HDR>`
`<LINE>line4</LINE>`
`<LINE>line5</LINE>`
`<LINE>line6</LINE>`

And I want a XLST script to transfer it to:

`<TOP>top</TOP>`
`<HDR>`
`header`
`<LINE>line1</LINE>`
`<LINE>line2</LINE>`
`<LINE>line3</LINE>`
`</HDR>`
`<HDR>`
`header`
`<LINE>line4</LINE>`
`<LINE>line5</LINE>`
`<LINE>line6</LINE>`
`</HDR>`

Thus: The `<HDR>`-tag **around** the LINES until next `<HDR>`-tag

Can someone help me, please to give me a xslt-script.

Comment: There are some similarly question (with answers) e.g. [Kayessian method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3836240/2115381) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188341/create-an-hierarchical-xml-form-an-flat-xml-a-like-book-description

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="LINE"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::HDR[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:copy-of select="TOP"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="HDR"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="HDR">
  <HDR>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </HDR>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment, wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <TOP>top</TOP>
    <HDR>header</HDR>
    <LINE>line1</LINE>
    <LINE>line2</LINE>
    <LINE>line3</LINE>
    <HDR>header</HDR>
    <LINE>line4</LINE>
    <LINE>line5</LINE>
    <LINE>line6</LINE>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<TOP>top</TOP>
<HDR>
   <LINE>line1</LINE>
   <LINE>line2</LINE>
   <LINE>line3</LINE>
</HDR>
<HDR>
   <LINE>line4</LINE>
   <LINE>line5</LINE>
   <LINE>line6</LINE>
</HDR>
```